# Sybase to SQL Server 2008 Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sybase

I had sybase database which contain table called (GOVS) which has a column called (GOV_NAME datatype varchar (50)) with arabic data, as i migrate this to SQL Server 2008
i get unreadable data in that column

Any Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `nvarchar` in sql server 2008  for this column. That support special character .

Answer (score 0):

Set the GOV_NAME column collation to Arabic_CI_AS. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx).

Comment: Thnx for your reply, but it didnt work. do i need to remigrate it after altering column?